# Unlocking HTC HD2 and installing Android

Tags: sim-unlocking, htc-hd2

I have HTC HD with Windows Mobile 6.5 installed and it is locked with Vodafone (Germany). If I want to install Android on it, do I have to unlock it first? Or it will be automatically unlocked in the process of installing Android?

Answer (score 1):

Neither.  Unlocking is entirely unrelated to the OS.